# pageCount property not exists in WKWebView

Tags: ios

I have a project need to refactor UIWebView to WKWebView, But the `pageCount` property is not exists in WKWebView, is there a similar property for alternative?

Answer (score 1):

WKWebView currently lacks equivalent APIs for paginating content.

- var paginationMode: UIWebPaginationMode
- var paginationBreakingMode: UIWebPaginationBreakingMode
- var pageLength: CGFloat
- var gapBetweenPages: CGFloat
- var pageCount: Int { get }
  in the current moment there's isn't any equivalent or similar property.